# How do I add a line break before every word that ends with a colon?

Tags: java, regex

I have a bunch of data that looks like this:

> Minimum system requirements CPU: Celeron M 420 1.6GHz, Sempron 3100+
>   RAM: 1 GB VGA: GeForce 205, Radeon HD 6320 OS: Windows XP/Windows
>   Vista/Windows 7/Windows 8 HDD: 4 GB Sound: DirectX compatible sound
>   card DirectX: 9.0c

And I'm trying to find a way to organize it so it would be easier to read at a later point in time. I was thinking adding a line break before every word that has a colon attached to it would be the simplest way to do so, but I'm not too familiar with Regex and I don't really know how to approach this problem. I would just search for each individual component separately, like "CPU:", "OS:" etc but it's not very consistent. Sometimes it's listed as Processor, sometimes it's CPU. Sometimes it's RAM, other times its memory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?=\\b\\w+:)", "\n");
```

(See [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29))

---

`(?=\b\w+:)` is a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that finds all 0-length substrings that are followed by `\b\w+:` (but does not include `\b\w+:` in the actual match). `\b` is a [word-boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and `\w+` is one or more word characters (alphanumeric characters and underscores, equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`). Finally, `:` is a literal colon. We replace all 0-length matches of this regex with a newline, `\n`.

Comment: YES, thank you! Could anyone explain what's going on here though? It works but Idk why :P

Comment: @user802519 I added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
System.out.println(yourData.replaceAll("\\w+:", "\n$0"));
```

- first parameter is regex that represents string of chars, digits or `_` that have `:` at its end
- second parameter will replace matched substring with new line `\n` and `$0` which means  `group(0)` which holds matched substring

Unfortunately this approach will also split `DirectX: 9.0c` in `Sound: DirectX compatible sound card DirectX: 9.0c`

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "blaala, blalal, alblalb, asa";
String separated[] = text.split(",");

for (int i=0; i<separated.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(separated[i]);
}
```

This will give you the oportunity to use each line separatly in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In these situations, I open the file in vim and then do a search and replace. In vim type:

```
:%s/\(\S\+\:\)/\r\1/g
```

this will turn that line into:

```
 Minimum system requirements 
 CPU: Celeron M 420 1.6GHz, Sempron 3100+ 
 RAM: 1 GB 
 VGA: GeForce 205, Radeon HD 6320 
 OS: Windows XP/Windows Vista/Windows 7/Windows 8
 HDD: 4 GB 
 Sound: DirectX compatible sound card 
 DirectX: 9.0c
```

this can also be done on the command line:

```
sed -i 's/\(\S\+\:\)/\n\1/g' <filename>
```